# I am trying to populate a list with properties and strings

Tags: c#, generic-collections, system.io.directory

I am trying to populate a list with property names and values, here is my code so far...

```
 public class DirPropeties { 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string HiddenStatus { get; set; }
    }
    public static List<string> GetDirAttributes(string path, bool IsHidden = true)
    {

        List<DirPropeties> FolderArrayList = new List<DirPropeties>();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = di.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subdirectories)
        {
            if (IsHidden)
            {
                //FolderArrayList.Add(dir.Name);
                FolderArrayList.Add(new DirPropeties { Name = dir.Name });
            }
            else if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
            {
                FolderArrayList.Add(new DirPropeties { Name = dir.Name });
            }

        };

        return FolderArrayList;
    }
```

I call it like so....

```
  List<string> DirectoryArrayList = new List<string>();
  DirectoryArrayList = BaseDirectory.GetDirAttributes(FileDetailsViewModel.FolderPath, FileDetailsViewModel.AllowHidden);
```

and I am trying to access the properties like so ...

```
   if (folderIndex >= DirectoryArrayList.Count) { break; }
   var folder = DirectoryArrayList[folderIndex];
   var label = new Label()
   {
        Text = folder.Name,
        FontSize = 20,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
   };
```

I get the following error on the return of the FolderArrayList...

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

and on the folder.Name i get the follwoing error...

**'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name'**

Can anyone help guid me as to what I need to do to solve this please?

Comment: `GetDirAttributes()` should return `List<DirPropeties>` not `List<string>` and `DirectoryArrayList` has the same problem.  Should also be `List<DirPropeties>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `List<string>` anywhere in this code.  Change

```
public static List<string> GetDirAttributes(string path, bool IsHidden = true)
```

to

```
public static List<DirPropeties> GetDirAttributes(string path, bool IsHidden = true)
```

Also change

```
List<string> DirectoryArrayList = new List<string>();
DirectoryArrayList = BaseDirectory.GetDirAttributes(FileDetailsViewModel.FolderPath, FileDetailsViewModel.AllowHidden);
```

to

```
var DirectoryArrayList = BaseDirectory.GetDirAttributes(FileDetailsViewModel.FolderPath, FileDetailsViewModel.AllowHidden);
```

You can also improve this code

```
if (IsHidden)
{
   //FolderArrayList.Add(dir.Name);
    FolderArrayList.Add(new DirPropeties { Name = dir.Name });
}
else if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    FolderArrayList.Add(new DirPropeties { Name = dir.Name });
}
```

to

```
if (IsHidden || (dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    FolderArrayList.Add(new DirPropeties { Name = dir.Name });
}
```

Comment: Awsome thank you, works like a charm, just one thing on the last part, it still needs to show the folders that have no hidden flag value, so i assume I will still need the else part?

Comment: Never mind i tested it, spoke before testing :-) I now have a better understanding of the logic thank you very much.